# Sequelize validade models by scenario

Tags: node.js, validation, models, sequelize.js

I'm using SequelizeJs as Active record on my system and I need validate different fields of my model based on the application current scenario.

So, if my model has the fields "name" and "email" I'd like validate "name" and "email" on registration, but only "email" on login.

The most used frameworks (like rails) have a parameter on validations that is "on: scenario" where scenario is the condition where the validations needs to work.

Is there a way to use scenarios on Sequelize?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share your code works to help others? Checked in Github discussion https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1768. Hope you have found some solution for scenario based validation.